# Get string or file in server side with socket programming

Tags: java, sockets

I have two projects in java application, the fist project is client side and the second project is the server side, Client side sends file or String to server via network, I use socket programming in my projects.
In client side I have many classes, I make object from each class and fill object and the object convert  to string  with Gson and send to server(with socket programming). In the server side I have a socket that listens to one port , my problem is in server side, I do not know which type sends to server via network for example client can send string and file  via network, in the server side I do not know which type(string or file) sends to server that I can take base on that format.
Please suggest a solution for resolve my problem.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

You can use similar to my below code

```
     ServerSocket sersock =null;
        Socket sock =null;
         sersock = new ServerSocket(3333); 
            System.out.println("Server ready to receive");
            sock = sersock.accept( );
            System.out.println("accepting client request");
            InputStream istream = sock.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader receiveRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(istream)); 
            String receiveMessage;
            while(true) { 
                if((receiveMessage = receiveRead.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println("receiveMessage server  "+receiveMessage);
}
```

Comment: its ok..i tried by passing String from client side...i think for file also same it looks..because client sends everything across the network as binary so we will get it in the form of socket reader so it should be same for both i guess...

Comment: thank you, i think that for big file( big size) , this code is slow, Is it correct?

Comment: ya but not that much slow..pass big file and calculate the time and see the performance.